# Basic MySQL query is breaking my HTML

Tags: php

I am having a weird issue with a MySQL query (it may be because I'm tired?). I've done this query so many times and don't understand where the issue is. The line that starts $result_torn is the line that's causing the problem. Everything below that line in the HTML doesn't get displayed, so the query is ending the code. I don't even get a PHP error message on the page? Here's the two lines of code. My connect is working fine since I don't get the error message there. The table is called 'torn.'

```
<?php
$sql_torn = "SELECT * FROM torn";
$result_torn = $mysqli->query($sql_torn);
?>
```

Any ideas why this would be happening? Seems pretty basic... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you check by `echo $mysqli->error;` ? Also paste bin your complete code, may possible error is somewhere after this lines.

Comment: Don't try debugging the *rendering* of an HTML document by looking at PHP. It is the HTML that is rendered, so look at the HTML (and CSS, etc). Figure out what is wrong with the HTML. Then figure out how to get the PHP to generate the HTML you actually want.

Comment: Did you created a `$mysqli` variable?
Did you tried to wrap it in a try-catch block?

Comment: what is `$mysql_i` here?  have you tried `mysqli_error()` ?

Comment: @Quentin, the HTML document loads fine, everything works on there. I've basically entered this code into the middle of the HTML to query and display some data and it's just preventing anything below it to display. I tried to do an if(!result_torn){echo $mysqli->error} after this code but nothing shows up. It's like nothing after the above code is being displayed...

Comment: How about setting `E_STRICT | E_ALL` and `display_errors = 1` [and all other error settings](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)

Comment: @MxmastaMills — You're still asking about the PHP. The browser can't see the PHP (or, if it can, then that is your problem!).  Look at the HTML source code and see what the output of the PHP is. It can't be the same as before you added that code if the rendering is breaking.

Comment: Was this query working before?? and if so....what changed between now and then?

Comment: in THAT point in your code, are you connected to db?? (maybe you have already disconnected in that point)

Comment: @Sharky No, I've run this code immediately after my db connect and I've got the database connect set up to give me an error message if I don't successfully connect which doesn't happen.

Comment: @KyleK, this is the inital setup of this page so it has not previously been working

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried....

```
  if(!$mysql->query($sql_torn)){
     echo $mysqli->error;
   }
```

If so....what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the inconvenience. My include of the DB connect was somehow flawed. I'm not quite sure how (I was drawing it from the root folder) but when I moved it to a new folder and included it, it worked.

Comment: that was my guess ;) no-connection